# querying across a workspace

Tags: rally

Is it possible to query for defects across an entire workspace?

We have defects that come in from our customer support portal that have a special "support id" field set, but they can be distributed to any of our projects.  I'd like to query for any such open defects across all the projects and sub projects in our workspace, but I think project scoping will prevent this.

Is there any way to do this?  I suppose I could put all our projects under one "super" project in the workspace and do it that way, but it seems like that would add a lot more navigation trouble for everybody in the organization to help solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually can do this by not specifying a project in your query (specifically setting project to null).  Here is an example using the RallyDataSource in the App SDK:

```
var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__', 
                                              '__PROJECT_OID__',
                                               '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__', 
                                              '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__'); 

var queryConfig = { 
    type: 'defect',
    key: 'defects',
    fetch: 'Name,State,Severity',
    project: null //query all projects in the workspace
 };

 rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, displayDefects);
```

Comment: That's cool Kyle I didn't know you could do that, thank you! I'm going to delete my previous inaccurate answer...

Comment: Ok, I presume you then have to create a custom app-- you can't do this with a custom grid?  Seems like this might be easy to add this option to a custom grid...

Comment: Yes, currently custom grids can only be pinned to a specific project (not a workspace).  This would be a cool (and likely pretty easy) addition to that panel...

Comment: I'll put that in as a Rally Idea